# Connection between different ways to calculate the knot determinant

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

I understand that there are multiple ways to calculate the knot determinant, one is through the Alexander polynomial, the other is by creating another matrix which uses the linesections and crossings, the last method is explained in [this pdf](https://www.dtubbenhauer.com/slides/geotop2022/4-knot-determinant.pdf).

My problem lies in the fact that I don't understand how both can give the same number, so in other words, how can two different things calculate the same thing. I think it's probably because of some deeper underlying thing which can be approached using these different methods, but I don't know what this 'thing' is.

So my question is, what is the connection between these two methods of calculating the knot determinant?

A useful answer would be a proof (or a referral to one) of the fact that these two methods will always give the same number or some insights in helping me understand why they must be the same.

Edit:
My definition of the Alexander polynomial is the polynomial which you get after computing the determinant of the Alexander matrix, you can find a more detailed explanation in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_polynomial#Computing_the_polynomial)

Comment: Which definition do you want to use for the Alexander polynomial? Which method “by linesections and crossings” do you mean? There are at least two. The core of the answer is in any case that the Alexander polynomial is very multifaceted. It can be defined in multiple ways that look very different.

Comment: With the method “by linesections and crossings” i mean the method that is explained in the link i added, shortly said for each intersection you give the entry 2 to the oversection and -1 to the undersections and 0 to every linesection that doesn't come forward in this intersection, you do this for every linesection and then put everything in a matrix. Then you delete one row and one column of the matrix and take the determinant.